# NSArray in NSArray addobject String

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I know how to add object in a single array

```
 [array addObject:@"lastName"]
```

but I have array which have two more sub-array.I want to create third sub-array and add lastName in that Array how can i do that
thanks in advance

Comment: Why? You probably don't want a really deep set of just arrays. Describe your data model in more detail.

Comment: An array is just an object.  You add it the same way you'd add an NSString.

Answer (score 0):

Very simply. What you just typed is how you do it. Just add the arrays you create to the next array and so on. You can continue nesting this one if you choose.

```
// Add your string to an array
[array3 addObject:@"lastName"]  

// Now add that array to another array
[array2 addObject:array3];

// Then you add that array to the next array
[array1 addObject:array2];
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/

Answer (score 0):

a litte more detailed:

```
NSArray *subArray1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C", nil];
NSArray *subArray2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"D", @"E", @"F", nil];

NSMutableArray *mainArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:subArray1, subArray2, nil];

NSArray *subArray3 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"G", @"H", @"I", nil];
[mainArray addObject:subArray3];
```

good luck ;)